# What is the syntax for adding vmargs to the wsimport maven plugin?

Tags: maven, wsimport

I tried to set accessExternalSchema with

```
<vmargs>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmargs>
```

This is not working because the property is a list of strings. How should I write this in my pom file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<vmArgs><vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg></vmArgs>
```